Problems with a direct TCP connection between a Raspberry and a Modbus device
I'm having problems with a direct TCP connection between a Raspberry and a Modbus device. If I connect a Fritzbox router in between, I can reach the Modbus device via the PI, but not with a direct connection. Has anyone an idea whats wrong, with my settings?
I have already tried various things:
sudo route add -net 192.168.178.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0

sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf -> activate net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

sudo apt install dhcpcd5:

sudo service dhcpcd status:

dhcpcd.service - DHCP Client Daemon on all interfaces
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)

     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-09-24 10:18:52 CEST; 18s ago
       Docs: man:dhcpcd(8)
   Main PID: 6775 (dhcpcd)
      Tasks: 7 (limit: 4451)
        CPU: 68ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service

             ├─6775 "dhcpcd: [manager] [ip4] [ip6]"
             ├─6776 "dhcpcd: [privileged proxy]"
             ├─6777 "dhcpcd: [network proxy]"
             ├─6778 "dhcpcd: [control proxy]"
             ├─6787 "dhcpcd: [BPF ARP] wlan0 192.168.178.156"
             ├─6788 "dhcpcd: [BPF BOOTP] eth0"
             └─6823 "dhcpcd: [BPF ARP] eth0 169.254.65.164"


Sep 24 10:18:53 EnviIQ dhcpcd[6776]: eth0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Sep 24 10:18:58 EnviIQ dhcpcd[6776]: wlan0: leased 192.168.178.156 for 864000 seconds
Sep 24 10:18:58 EnviIQ dhcpcd[6776]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.178.0/24
Sep 24 10:18:58 EnviIQ dhcpcd[6776]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.178.1
Sep 24 10:18:58 EnviIQ dhcpcd[6776]: eth0: probing for an IPv4LL address
Sep 24 10:19:02 EnviIQ dhcpcd[6776]: eth0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.65.164
Sep 24 10:19:02 EnviIQ dhcpcd[6776]: eth0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
Sep 24 10:19:02 EnviIQ dhcpcd[6776]: wlan0: failed to request DHCPv6 information
Sep 24 10:19:02 EnviIQ dhcpcd[6776]: wlan0: requesting DHCPv6 information
Sep 24 10:19:04 EnviIQ dhcpcd[6776]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available

But nothing works so far.
The settings look like this:
Modbus device:
Settings of the Modbus device:
Static IP: 192.168.178.123 
Gateway: 192.168.178.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0

PI: ifconfig
br-0967c6d6ecd8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:22ff:fe5d:5ce8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:22:5d:5c:e8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11802462  bytes 687986773 (656.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7687065  bytes 499280012 (476.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:a4:38:b7:ba  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d8:3a:dd:bf:3d:84  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4704  bytes 216384 (211.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 802  bytes 148186 (144.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 106

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 18  bytes 2466 (2.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18  bytes 2466 (2.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth13c42a8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::2876:83ff:fe3b:e265  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 2a:76:83:3b:e2:65  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 528  bytes 35300 (34.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 821  bytes 344203 (336.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth87a0d72: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::7827:dcff:fe29:5993  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7a:27:dc:29:59:93  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11801934  bytes 853185941 (813.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 7686603  bytes 498964599 (475.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.125  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::d87f:7f96:664:7af6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a07:4d04:3b5:6b01:6167:3bba:ae62:53a1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether d8:3a:dd:bf:3d:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13071729  bytes 959220824 (914.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 524714  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15090731  bytes 1027549611 (979.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: Transmit-only
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: Transmit-only
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                     100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Auto-negotiation: on
master-slave cfg: preferred slave
master-slave status: slave
Port: Twisted Pair
PHYAD: 1
Transceiver: external
MDI-X: Unknown
Supports Wake-on: d
Wake-on: d
Link detected: yes


Welcome. eth0 does not have an IP address.  Please edit into the question what you have done to facilitate a "direct connection"; it is not quite as simple as just plugging in the cable at both ends (the reason it works with the router in the middle is probably because the Pi is configured to do DHCP negotiation to get an address, but the modbus device does not run a DHCP server like the router does).

Which Pi? What OS is installed (detail including version)?

I use a PI Model 5 with 2024-03-15-raspios-bookworm-arm64-lite

As per my comment, this works with a router in the middle because you are using a DHCP client with the interface, and it obtains an IP address from the router, but the modbus device does not provide this.
I'm presuming that the modbus device does not have any other networking connection than the eth port and that the IP address it is configured with matches your LAN subnet, intended for when it is plugged into the router.  This all by itself is a problem because it's the same subnet used by the Pi's wifi; if you want to connect it directly to the Pi either you have to disable wifi on the Pi or use a different address on the modbus.
Here I'm going to use 10.100.0.1/24 for the pi, so you could use anything in 10.100.0.[2-255] for the modbus.
While dhcpcd can be configured to apply a static ip, it will still use this to try for a DHCP lease (since normally a router must still be informed of and confirm the address) unless you also configure it not to do that, but man dhcpcd.conf says that "is only useful when allowing IPv4LL", which is probably not what you want either as this can be awkward (the log output in the question shows it assigning an arbitrary ipv4ll address).  But you could try (in /etc/dhcpcd.conf):
interface eth0
    noipv4ll
    noipv6
    nodhcp
    static ip_address=10.100.0.1/24

If that does not work (there's not much point to using dhcpcd for this, and it may cause problems anyway), just disable it there instead:
denyinterfaces eth0

And try this script (with sudo), which could then be configured to run at boot (when there's no cable attached, it won't matter):
#!/bin/sh

ip link set eth0 up
ip addr add 10.100.0.1/24 dev eth0

The kernel should automatically configure the route, you can check this with ip r.
